# Getting Accurate Coordinates when App Brought to Foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I need my app to display very accurate latitude and longitude coordinates when it is brought from the background to the foreground.

I am having quite a bit of trouble doing this. When I put my app in the background, the location services turn off. I have considered enabling the background location mode, but am aware that doing so may cause the user's battery to drain. I have also attempted to use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` but that doesn't seem to be accurate.

My view has a button that displays the user's coordinates when clicked. When the button is clicked while walking around, the coordinates are accurate. But if the user awakens the app and immediately clicks the button, the coordinates are way off. Can anyone help me with this? Is enabling the background location mode my only option? Can I disable the button until the location is accurate? any help would be greatly appreciated!

My view pulls the coordinates from a locationManager that is setup in my app delegate like below:

**Here is the view:**

```
-(void>buttonClick {

NSString *userLatitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
getUserLatitude];

NSString *userLongitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
getUserLongitude];
}
```

**Here is the app delegate:**

```
- (NSString *)getUserLatitude {
    NSString *userLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    return userLatitude;
}

- (NSString *)getUserLongitude {
    NSString *userLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    return userLongitude;
}
```

Comment: Did you try calling the location services from app delegate?

Comment: yes, the location services are setup in the app delegate. I will update my question to show what I am doing.

Comment: Your code is repetitive. Return location object from the app delegate and let the view controller take care of formatting.

Answer (score 1):

update you location manager on button click.You need to wait until it gives accurate location.

check this 
[How to wait for until location Manager to get high accurate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833647/how-to-wait-for-until-location-manager-to-get-high-accurate-data)

Answer (score 0):

In the docs to `startUpdatingLocation` it says:

> Calling this method several times in succession does not automatically result in new events being generated. Calling stopUpdatingLocation in between, however, does cause a new initial event to be sent the next time you call this method.

So I would recommend "re-initializing" the location manager

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Use the delegate callback `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` which should be called after a couple of seconds to update the coordinates to display to the user.

PS: if you used deferred location updates you have to make sure you call `disallowDeferredLocationUpdates`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are using the wrong approach.

As you were able to see, GPS **need** a certain amount of time to get a fix location, this is because of how GPS works and you can't change it. A GPS can take up to a minute to get a precise location, ad for this reason in all the iOS devices (and basically all the smartphone now in the market) you have assisted GPS which use cellurar radio and wi-fi triangulation in order to provide a almost instantly an approximate location. In fact the ability of specify the `desiredAccuracy` is used by CLLocationManager to turn on or off the specific sensor, for example if you specify `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` there is a good change that the GPS is never turned on and only cellular + wifi is use (because this is faster and save a lot of battery)

`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` as the name suggest is used only for significant (wide/big) change in user location and doesn't solve your problem. Keep in mind that as user I don't like when an app keeps monitor my location even if I know it doesn't need it: this can be a reason to kill or uninstall you app.

That said it think that the best thing you can do is simply wait or tell the user that you showing him a location but can be not accurate (take a look for example to RunKeeper). A lot of things in iOS happens asynchronously and instead of force your app design as this things happens instantaneously, embrace this asynchronous world.

If by design you require to have a precise location, you can disable the button, and wait until the CLLocationManger's delegate tell (`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`) you that you have reached the desired accuracy (you can to this by looking at `CLLocation`'s `horizontalAccuracy`) and then enable the button.

A little notice: CLLocationManager caches the last locations, therefor be sure to check the timestamp of the CLLocation before do any logic.